# OnExit is fired twice after click on TListView

Tags: c++builder, vcl, setfocus, tlistview

in the OnExit event of a TEdit I make some validation and set the focus back to the Edit, if the edit doesn't have a valid content. This works fine when I try to switch to an other edit field. When I try to enter a TListView component the OnExit event gets called again after calling SetFocus().

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1Exit(TObject *Sender)
{
   //if entry not valid
   dynamic_cast<TEdit*>(Sender)->SetFocus();
}
```

Has anybody an idea why the event is called twice when a TListView is entered?